# Create a 5 x 5 matrix using Nested list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, matrix, nested-lists

Matrices can be represented as a `list of lists` in Python.

For example a `5 x 5` matrix with values `0` to `4` in each row can be written as:

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
          [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

How to recreate this matrix by using nested listed comprehensions?

Here is my code:

```
num = [[num1,num2,num3,num4,num5] for num1 in range(5) for num2 in range(5)for num3 in range(5)for num4 in range(5)for num5 in range(5)]
```

And it produce the following output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 4],
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 4],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 4],
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 4, 4],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 4],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 4],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 4],
 [0, 0, 1, 3, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 3, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 3, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 3, 3],
 [0, 0, 1, 3, 4],
 [0, 0, 1, 4, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 4, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 4, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 4, 3],
 [0, 0, 1, 4, 4],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 2, 0, 4],
 [0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 2, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 2, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 2, 1, 4],
 [0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
 [0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 2, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 2, 2, 4],
 [0, 0, 2, 3, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 3, 1],
 [0, 0, 2, 3, 2],
 [0, 0, 2, 3, 3],
 [0, 0, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 0, 2, 4, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 4, 1],
 [0, 0, 2, 4, 2],
 [0, 0, 2, 4, 3],
 [0, 0, 2, 4, 4],
 [0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 3, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 3, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 3, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
 [0, 0, 3, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 3, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 3, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 3, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 3, 1, 4],
 [0, 0, 3, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 3, 2, 1],
 [0, 0, 3, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 3, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 3, 2, 4],
 [0, 0, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 0, 3, 3, 1],
 [0, 0, 3, 3, 2],
 [0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
 [0, 0, 3, 3, 4],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 0],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 1],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 2],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 3],
 [0, 0, 3, 4, 4],
 [0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 4, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 4, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 4, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 4, 0, 4],
 [0, 0, 4, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 4, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 4, 1, 2],
 [0, 0, 4, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 4, 1, 4],
 [0, 0, 4, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 4, 2, 1],
 [0, 0, 4, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 4, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 4, 2, 4],
 [0, 0, 4, 3, 0],
 [0, 0, 4, 3, 1],
 [0, 0, 4, 3, 2],
 [0, 0, 4, 3, 3],
 [0, 0, 4, 3, 4],
 [0, 0, 4, 4, 0],
 [0, 0, 4, 4, 1],
 [0, 0, 4, 4, 2],
 [0, 0, 4, 4, 3],
 [0, 0, 4, 4, 4],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 4],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 4],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 2],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 4],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 2],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 3],
 [0, 1, 0, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 0, 4, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 4, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 4, 2],
 [0, 1, 0, 4, 3],
 [0, 1, 0, 4, 4],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 2],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 4],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 4],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [0, 1, 1, 3, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 3, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 3, 2],
 [0, 1, 1, 3, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 1, 4, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 4, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 4, 2],
 [0, 1, 1, 4, 3],
 [0, 1, 1, 4, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 0, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 0, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 2, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 1],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 4],
 [0, 1, 3, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 3, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 3, 0, 2],
 [0, 1, 3, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 3, 0, 4],
 [0, 1, 3, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 3, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 3, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 3, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 3, 1, 4],
 [0, 1, 3, 2, 0],
 [0, 1, 3, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 3, 2, 2],
 [0, 1, 3, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 3, 2, 4],
 [0, 1, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 1, 3, 3, 1],
 [0, 1, 3, 3, 2],
 [0, 1, 3, 3, 3],
 [0, 1, 3, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 0],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 1],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 2],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 3],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 4],
 [0, 1, 4, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 4, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 4, 0, 2],
 [0, 1, 4, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 4, 0, 4],
 [0, 1, 4, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 4, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 4, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 4, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 4, 1, 4],
 [0, 1, 4, 2, 0],
 [0, 1, 4, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 4, 2, 2],
 [0, 1, 4, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 4, 2, 4],
 [0, 1, 4, 3, 0],
 [0, 1, 4, 3, 1],
 [0, 1, 4, 3, 2],
 [0, 1, 4, 3, 3],
 [0, 1, 4, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 4, 4, 0],
 [0, 1, 4, 4, 1],
 [0, 1, 4, 4, 2],
 [0, 1, 4, 4, 3],
 [0, 1, 4, 4, 4],
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 3],
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 4],
 [0, 2, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 2, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 0, 1, 3],
 [0, 2, 0, 1, 4],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 4],
 [0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 3, 1],
 [0, 2, 0, 3, 2],
 [0, 2, 0, 3, 3],
 [0, 2, 0, 3, 4],
 [0, 2, 0, 4, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 4, 1],
 [0, 2, 0, 4, 2],
 [0, 2, 0, 4, 3],
 [0, 2, 0, 4, 4],
 [0, 2, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 1, 0, 2],
 [0, 2, 1, 0, 3],
 [0, 2, 1, 0, 4],
 [0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 2, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 2, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 1, 1, 3],
 [0, 2, 1, 1, 4],
 [0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 1, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 2, 1, 2, 4],
 [0, 2, 1, 3, 0],
 [0, 2, 1, 3, 1],
 [0, 2, 1, 3, 2],
 [0, 2, 1, 3, 3],
 [0, 2, 1, 3, 4],
 [0, 2, 1, 4, 0],
 [0, 2, 1, 4, 1],
 [0, 2, 1, 4, 2],
 [0, 2, 1, 4, 3],
 [0, 2, 1, 4, 4],
 [0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
 [0, 2, 2, 0, 3],
 [0, 2, 2, 0, 4],
 [0, 2, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 1, 1],
 [0, 2, 2, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 2, 1, 3],
 [0, 2, 2, 1, 4],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 3],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 4],
 [0, 2, 2, 3, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 3, 1],
 [0, 2, 2, 3, 2],
 [0, 2, 2, 3, 3],
 [0, 2, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 2, 2, 4, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 4, 1],
 [0, 2, 2, 4, 2],
 [0, 2, 2, 4, 3],
 [0, 2, 2, 4, 4],
 [0, 2, 3, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 3, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 3, 0, 2],
 [0, 2, 3, 0, 3],
 [0, 2, 3, 0, 4],
 [0, 2, 3, 1, 0],
 [0, 2, 3, 1, 1],
 [0, 2, 3, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 3, 1, 3],
 [0, 2, 3, 1, 4],
 [0, 2, 3, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 3, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 3, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 3, 2, 3],
 [0, 2, 3, 2, 4],
 [0, 2, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 2, 3, 3, 1],
 [0, 2, 3, 3, 2],
 [0, 2, 3, 3, 3],
 [0, 2, 3, 3, 4],
 [0, 2, 3, 4, 0],
 [0, 2, 3, 4, 1],
 [0, 2, 3, 4, 2],
 [0, 2, 3, 4, 3],
 [0, 2, 3, 4, 4],
 [0, 2, 4, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 4, 0, 1],
 [0, 2, 4, 0, 2],
 [0, 2, 4, 0, 3],
 [0, 2, 4, 0, 4],
 [0, 2, 4, 1, 0],
 [0, 2, 4, 1, 1],
 [0, 2, 4, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 4, 1, 3],
 [0, 2, 4, 1, 4],
 [0, 2, 4, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 4, 2, 1],
 [0, 2, 4, 2, 2],
 [0, 2, 4, 2, 3],
 [0, 2, 4, 2, 4],
 [0, 2, 4, 3, 0],
 [0, 2, 4, 3, 1],
 [0, 2, 4, 3, 2],
 [0, 2, 4, 3, 3],
 [0, 2, 4, 3, 4],
 [0, 2, 4, 4, 0],
 [0, 2, 4, 4, 1],
 [0, 2, 4, 4, 2],
 [0, 2, 4, 4, 3],
 [0, 2, 4, 4, 4],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 3],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 4],
 [0, 3, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 3, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 3, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 3, 0, 1, 3],
 [0, 3, 0, 1, 4],
 [0, 3, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 3, 0, 2, 1],
 [0, 3, 0, 2, 2],
 [0, 3, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 0, 2, 4],
 [0, 3, 0, 3, 0],
 [0, 3, 0, 3, 1],
 [0, 3, 0, 3, 2],
 [0, 3, 0, 3, 3],
 [0, 3, 0, 3, 4],
 [0, 3, 0, 4, 0],
 [0, 3, 0, 4, 1],
 [0, 3, 0, 4, 2],
 [0, 3, 0, 4, 3],
 [0, 3, 0, 4, 4],
 [0, 3, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 3, 1, 0, 2],
 [0, 3, 1, 0, 3],
 [0, 3, 1, 0, 4],
 [0, 3, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 3, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 3, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 3, 1, 1, 3],
 [0, 3, 1, 1, 4],
 [0, 3, 1, 2, 0],
 [0, 3, 1, 2, 1],
 [0, 3, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 3, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 1, 2, 4],
 [0, 3, 1, 3, 0],
 [0, 3, 1, 3, 1],
 [0, 3, 1, 3, 2],
 [0, 3, 1, 3, 3],
 [0, 3, 1, 3, 4],
 [0, 3, 1, 4, 0],
 [0, 3, 1, 4, 1],
 [0, 3, 1, 4, 2],
 [0, 3, 1, 4, 3],
 [0, 3, 1, 4, 4],
 [0, 3, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 2, 0, 1],
 [0, 3, 2, 0, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 0, 3],
 [0, 3, 2, 0, 4],
 [0, 3, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 3, 2, 1, 1],
 [0, 3, 2, 1, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 1, 3],
 [0, 3, 2, 1, 4],
 [0, 3, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 3, 2, 2, 1],
 [0, 3, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 2, 2, 4],
 [0, 3, 2, 3, 0],
 [0, 3, 2, 3, 1],
 [0, 3, 2, 3, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 3, 3],
 [0, 3, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 3, 2, 4, 0],
 [0, 3, 2, 4, 1],
 [0, 3, 2, 4, 2],
 [0, 3, 2, 4, 3],
 [0, 3, 2, 4, 4],
 [0, 3, 3, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 3, 0, 1],
 [0, 3, 3, 0, 2],
 [0, 3, 3, 0, 3],
 [0, 3, 3, 0, 4],
 [0, 3, 3, 1, 0],
 [0, 3, 3, 1, 1],
 [0, 3, 3, 1, 2],
 [0, 3, 3, 1, 3],
 [0, 3, 3, 1, 4],
 [0, 3, 3, 2, 0],
 [0, 3, 3, 2, 1],
 [0, 3, 3, 2, 2],
 [0, 3, 3, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 3, 2, 4],
 [0, 3, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 3, 3, 3, 1],
 [0, 3, 3, 3, 2],
 [0, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 [0, 3, 3, 3, 4],
 [0, 3, 3, 4, 0],
 [0, 3, 3, 4, 1],
 [0, 3, 3, 4, 2],
 [0, 3, 3, 4, 3],
 [0, 3, 3, 4, 4],
 [0, 3, 4, 0, 0],
 [0, 3, 4, 0, 1],
 [0, 3, 4, 0, 2],
 [0, 3, 4, 0, 3],
 [0, 3, 4, 0, 4],
 [0, 3, 4, 1, 0],
 [0, 3, 4, 1, 1],
 [0, 3, 4, 1, 2],
 [0, 3, 4, 1, 3],
 [0, 3, 4, 1, 4],
 [0, 3, 4, 2, 0],
 [0, 3, 4, 2, 1],
 [0, 3, 4, 2, 2],
 [0, 3, 4, 2, 3],
 [0, 3, 4, 2, 4],
 [0, 3, 4, 3, 0],
 [0, 3, 4, 3, 1],
 [0, 3, 4, 3, 2],
 [0, 3, 4, 3, 3],
 [0, 3, 4, 3, 4],
 [0, 3, 4, 4, 0],
 [0, 3, 4, 4, 1],
 [0, 3, 4, 4, 2],
 [0, 3, 4, 4, 3],
 [0, 3, 4, 4, 4],
 [0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 4, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 4, 0, 0, 3],
 [0, 4, 0, 0, 4],
 [0, 4, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 4, 0, 1, 2],
 [0, 4, 0, 1, 3],
 [0, 4, 0, 1, 4],
 [0, 4, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 2, 1],
 [0, 4, 0, 2, 2],
 [0, 4, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 4, 0, 2, 4],
 [0, 4, 0, 3, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 3, 1],
 [0, 4, 0, 3, 2],
 [0, 4, 0, 3, 3],
 [0, 4, 0, 3, 4],
 [0, 4, 0, 4, 0],
 [0, 4, 0, 4, 1],
 [0, 4, 0, 4, 2],
 [0, 4, 0, 4, 3],
 [0, 4, 0, 4, 4],
 [0, 4, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 4, 1, 0, 2],
 [0, 4, 1, 0, 3],
 [0, 4, 1, 0, 4],
 [0, 4, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 4, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 4, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 4, 1, 1, 3],
 [0, 4, 1, 1, 4],
 [0, 4, 1, 2, 0],
 [0, 4, 1, 2, 1],
 [0, 4, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 4, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 4, 1, 2, 4],
 [0, 4, 1, 3, 0],
 [0, 4, 1, 3, 1],
 [0, 4, 1, 3, 2],
 [0, 4, 1, 3, 3],
 [0, 4, 1, 3, 4],
 [0, 4, 1, 4, 0],
 [0, 4, 1, 4, 1],
 [0, 4, 1, 4, 2],
 [0, 4, 1, 4, 3],
 [0, 4, 1, 4, 4],
 [0, 4, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 2, 0, 1],
 [0, 4, 2, 0, 2],
 [0, 4, 2, 0, 3],
 [0, 4, 2, 0, 4],
 [0, 4, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 4, 2, 1, 1],
 [0, 4, 2, 1, 2],
 [0, 4, 2, 1, 3],
 [0, 4, 2, 1, 4],
 [0, 4, 2, 2, 0],
 [0, 4, 2, 2, 1],
 [0, 4, 2, 2, 2],
 [0, 4, 2, 2, 3],
 [0, 4, 2, 2, 4],
 [0, 4, 2, 3, 0],
 [0, 4, 2, 3, 1],
 [0, 4, 2, 3, 2],
 [0, 4, 2, 3, 3],
 [0, 4, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 4, 2, 4, 0],
 [0, 4, 2, 4, 1],
 [0, 4, 2, 4, 2],
 [0, 4, 2, 4, 3],
 [0, 4, 2, 4, 4],
 [0, 4, 3, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 3, 0, 1],
 [0, 4, 3, 0, 2],
 [0, 4, 3, 0, 3],
 [0, 4, 3, 0, 4],
 [0, 4, 3, 1, 0],
 [0, 4, 3, 1, 1],
 [0, 4, 3, 1, 2],
 [0, 4, 3, 1, 3],
 [0, 4, 3, 1, 4],
 [0, 4, 3, 2, 0],
 [0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [0, 4, 3, 2, 2],
 [0, 4, 3, 2, 3],
 [0, 4, 3, 2, 4],
 [0, 4, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 4, 3, 3, 1],
 [0, 4, 3, 3, 2],
 [0, 4, 3, 3, 3],
 [0, 4, 3, 3, 4],
 [0, 4, 3, 4, 0],
 [0, 4, 3, 4, 1],
 [0, 4, 3, 4, 2],
 [0, 4, 3, 4, 3],
 [0, 4, 3, 4, 4],
 [0, 4, 4, 0, 0],
 [0, 4, 4, 0, 1],
 [0, 4, 4, 0, 2],
 [0, 4, 4, 0, 3],
 [0, 4, 4, 0, 4],
 [0, 4, 4, 1, 0],
 [0, 4, 4, 1, 1],
 [0, 4, 4, 1, 2],
 [0, 4, 4, 1, 3],
 [0, 4, 4, 1, 4],
 [0, 4, 4, 2, 0],
 [0, 4, 4, 2, 1],
 [0, 4, 4, 2, 2],
 [0, 4, 4, 2, 3],
 [0, 4, 4, 2, 4],
 [0, 4, 4, 3, 0],
 [0, 4, 4, 3, 1],
 [0, 4, 4, 3, 2],
 [0, 4, 4, 3, 3],
 [0, 4, 4, 3, 4],
 [0, 4, 4, 4, 0],
 [0, 4, 4, 4, 1],
 [0, 4, 4, 4, 2],
 [0, 4, 4, 4, 3],
 [0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 4],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 2],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 3],
 [1, 0, 0, 1, 4],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 3],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 4],
 [1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 3, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 3, 2],
 [1, 0, 0, 3, 3],
 [1, 0, 0, 3, 4],
 [1, 0, 0, 4, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 4, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 4, 2],
 [1, 0, 0, 4, 3],
 [1, 0, 0, 4, 4],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 4],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 2],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 3],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 4],
 [1, 0, 1, 2, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 0, 1, 2, 4],
 [1, 0, 1, 3, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 3, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 3, 2],
 [1, 0, 1, 3, 3],
 [1, 0, 1, 3, 4],
 [1, 0, 1, 4, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 4, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 4, 2],
 [1, 0, 1, 4, 3],
 [1, 0, 1, 4, 4],
 [1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 2, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 2, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 2, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 2, 0, 4],
 [1, 0, 2, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 2, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 2, 1, 2],
 [1, 0, 2, 1, 3],
 [1, 0, 2, 1, 4],
 [1, 0, 2, 2, 0],
 [1, 0, 2, 2, 1],
 [1, 0, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 0, 2, 2, 3],
 [1, 0, 2, 2, 4],
 [1, 0, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 0, 2, 3, 1],
 [1, 0, 2, 3, 2],
 [1, 0, 2, 3, 3],
 [1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 0, 2, 4, 0],
 [1, 0, 2, 4, 1],
 [1, 0, 2, 4, 2],
 [1, 0, 2, 4, 3],
 [1, 0, 2, 4, 4],
 [1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 3, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 3, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 3, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 3, 0, 4],
 [1, 0, 3, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 3, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 3, 1, 2],
 [1, 0, 3, 1, 3],
 [1, 0, 3, 1, 4],
 [1, 0, 3, 2, 0],
 [1, 0, 3, 2, 1],
 [1, 0, 3, 2, 2],
 [1, 0, 3, 2, 3],
 [1, 0, 3, 2, 4],
 [1, 0, 3, 3, 0],
 [1, 0, 3, 3, 1],
 [1, 0, 3, 3, 2],
 [1, 0, 3, 3, 3],
 [1, 0, 3, 3, 4],
 [1, 0, 3, 4, 0],
 [1, 0, 3, 4, 1],
 [1, 0, 3, 4, 2],
 [1, 0, 3, 4, 3],
 [1, 0, 3, 4, 4],
 [1, 0, 4, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 4, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 4, 0, 2],
 [1, 0, 4, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 4, 0, 4],
 [1, 0, 4, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 4, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 4, 1, 2],
 [1, 0, 4, 1, 3],
 [1, 0, 4, 1, 4],
 [1, 0, 4, 2, 0],
 [1, 0, 4, 2, 1],
 [1, 0, 4, 2, 2],
 [1, 0, 4, 2, 3],
 [1, 0, 4, 2, 4],
 [1, 0, 4, 3, 0],
 [1, 0, 4, 3, 1],
 [1, 0, 4, 3, 2],
 [1, 0, 4, 3, 3],
 [1, 0, 4, 3, 4],
 [1, 0, 4, 4, 0],
 [1, 0, 4, 4, 1],
 [1, 0, 4, 4, 2],
 [1, 0, 4, 4, 3],
 [1, 0, 4, 4, 4],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 3],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 4],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 3],
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 4],
 [1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 2, 3],
 [1, 1, 0, 2, 4],
 [1, 1, 0, 3, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 3, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 3, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 3, 3],
 [1, 1, 0, 3, 4],
 [1, 1, 0, 4, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 4, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 4, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 4, 3],
 [1, 1, 0, 4, 4],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 3],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 4],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 4],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 4],
 [1, 1, 1, 3, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 3, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 3, 3],
 [1, 1, 1, 3, 4],
 [1, 1, 1, 4, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 4, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 4, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 4, 3],
 [1, 1, 1, 4, 4],
 [1, 1, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 2, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 2, 0, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 0, 3],
 [1, 1, 2, 0, 4],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 3],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 4],
 [1, 1, 2, 2, 0],
 [1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
 [1, 1, 2, 2, 4],
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 1],
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 1, 2, 4, 0],
 [1, 1, 2, 4, 1],
 [1, 1, 2, 4, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 4, 3],
 [1, 1, 2, 4, 4],
 [1, 1, 3, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 3, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 3, 0, 2],
 [1, 1, 3, 0, 3],
 [1, 1, 3, 0, 4],
 [1, 1, 3, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 3, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 3, 1, 3],
 [1, 1, 3, 1, 4],
 [1, 1, 3, 2, 0],
 [1, 1, 3, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 3, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 3, 2, 3],
 [1, 1, 3, 2, 4],
 [1, 1, 3, 3, 0],
 [1, 1, 3, 3, 1],
 [1, 1, 3, 3, 2],
 [1, 1, 3, 3, 3],
 [1, 1, 3, 3, 4],
 [1, 1, 3, 4, 0],
 [1, 1, 3, 4, 1],
 [1, 1, 3, 4, 2],
 [1, 1, 3, 4, 3],
 [1, 1, 3, 4, 4],
 [1, 1, 4, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 4, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 4, 0, 2],
 [1, 1, 4, 0, 3],
 [1, 1, 4, 0, 4],
 [1, 1, 4, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 4, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 4, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 4, 1, 3],
 [1, 1, 4, 1, 4],
 [1, 1, 4, 2, 0],
 [1, 1, 4, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 4, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 4, 2, 3],
 [1, 1, 4, 2, 4],
 [1, 1, 4, 3, 0],
 [1, 1, 4, 3, 1],
 [1, 1, 4, 3, 2],
 [1, 1, 4, 3, 3],
 [1, 1, 4, 3, 4],
 [1, 1, 4, 4, 0],
 [1, 1, 4, 4, 1],
 [1, 1, 4, 4, 2],
 [1, 1, 4, 4, 3],
 [1, 1, 4, 4, 4],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 2],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 3],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 4],
 [1, 2, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 0, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 0, 1, 4],
 [1, 2, 0, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 0, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 0, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 0, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 0, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 0, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 0, 3, 3],
 [1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 0, 4, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 4, 1],
 [1, 2, 0, 4, 2],
 [1, 2, 0, 4, 3],
 [1, 2, 0, 4, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 0, 2],
 [1, 2, 1, 0, 3],
 [1, 2, 1, 0, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 1, 1, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 3],
 [1, 2, 1, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 4, 0],
 [1, 2, 1, 4, 1],
 [1, 2, 1, 4, 2],
 [1, 2, 1, 4, 3],
 [1, 2, 1, 4, 4],
 [1, 2, 2, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 2, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 2, 0, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 0, 3],
 [1, 2, 2, 0, 4],
 [1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 2, 1, 4],
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 2, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 2, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
 [1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 2, 4, 0],
 [1, 2, 2, 4, 1],
 [1, 2, 2, 4, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 4, 3],
 [1, 2, 2, 4, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 1, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
 [1, 2, 4, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 4, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 4, 0, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 0, 3],
 [1, 2, 4, 0, 4],
 [1, 2, 4, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 4, 1, 1],
 [1, 2, 4, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 4, 1, 4],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 0],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 4, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 4, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 4, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 3, 3],
 [1, 2, 4, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 4, 4, 0],
 [1, 2, 4, 4, 1],
 [1, 2, 4, 4, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 4, 3],
 [1, 2, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Please someone help me to solve this.

Comment: Try `arr = [list(range(5)) for _ in range(5)]`?

Comment: Given that you have a fixed inner list, just do `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] for i in range(5)]`

Comment: You have 5 nested loops, which produces 5 x 5 x 5 x 5 x 5 entries. You need 2 nested loops to produce 5 rows of 5 entries (25 total).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> [[j for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
```

---

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Ohh! It's so easy. I've tried for long times Thanks friend :)

Comment: # List of lists
@Amir_Kalimi and @shaik_moeed: You can make it more concise and pythonic.  With `nrows, ncols = (5,5)`, the list of lists is given by: 
`a = [[x for x in range(ncols)]]*nrows`

Comment: @CypherX, Using `list * list` does have some drawbacks. If you tried to change `a[2][2]`, it will change all elements in `a[*][2]` because it is referencing to the same object. So, it is not recommended to use without knowing.

Comment: Why is this question closed for more answers? I tried posting my solution `[[x for x in range(ncols)]]*nrows` to it, but could not as it seems it has been closed for any more responses.

Comment: @shaikmoeed: I checked with the following and did not see other lists getting overwritten. Am I missing something? `a[0] = [9]*5`.

Comment: @CypherX Check with `list of list`, which you have suggested as answer in the above comment

Comment: @shaikmoeed Okay. I see. If I do `a[1][2] = 9` that just changes all `a[*][2]` to 9. Thank you for pointing this out. :)